# Lenovo laptop with Intel CPU remains at lowest clock

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, performance

I have an Lenovo T440p with an Intel Core i5 4300M CPU. 8GB RAM, SSD running with Windows 7 (preinstalled).

The only thing I did not like about this laptop was the screen, which I replaced (the whole LCD unit - including the hinges) with a full-hd version. It was rather easy; I did not have to remove the CPU/GPU.

Recently I noticed is that the laptop has become really slow, especially running VMs. In task manager I can see that the CPU is many times at 100% on all cores. `CPU-Z` is reporting that the CPU is running at the lowest possible clock:

- Core Speed: 798.85 MHz
- Multiplier x8
- Bus Speed 99.87 MHz
- Core Voltage  of 0.659 V

*(full details at the end)*

I have set Windows already to "Maximum Performance" in the energy settings. I have also taken out the battery and am running with the power adapter. I also set the Lenovo Power Manager to maximum performance. Sadly, no improvement.

What else can I try?

```
Processors Information
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Processor 1         ID = 0
    Number of cores     2 (max 8)
    Number of threads   4 (max 16)
    Name            Intel Core i5 4300M
    Codename        Haswell
    Specification       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300M CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Package (platform ID)   Socket 947 rPGA (0x4)
    CPUID           6.C.3
    Extended CPUID      6.3C
    Core Stepping       C0
    Technology      22 nm
    TDP Limit       37.0 Watts
    Tjmax           100.0 °C
    Core Speed      799.0 MHz
    Multiplier x Bus Speed  8.0 x 99.9 MHz
    Stock frequency     2600 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX, AVX2, FMA3, TSX
    L1 Data cache       2 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    2 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        2 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L3 cache        3 MBytes, 12-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    FID/VID Control     yes


    Turbo Mode      supported, enabled
    Max non-turbo ratio 26x
    Max turbo ratio     33x
    Max efficiency ratio    8x
    O/C bins        none
    Ratio 1 core        33x
    Ratio 2 cores       32x
    Ratio 3 cores       32x
    Ratio 4 cores       32x
    TSC         2596.8 MHz
    APERF           794.7 MHz
    MPERF           2581.1 MHz
    IA Voltage Mode     PCU adaptive
    IA Voltage Offset   0 mV
    GT Voltage Mode     PCU adaptive
    GT Voltage Offset   0 mV
    LLC/Ring Voltage Mode   PCU adaptive
    LLC/Ring Voltage Offset 0 mV
    Agent Voltage Mode  PCU adaptive
    Agent Voltage Offset    0 mV

    Temperature 0       55°C (131°F) [0x2D] (Core #0)
    Temperature 1       59°C (138°F) [0x29] (Package)
    Power 0         11.12 W (Package)
    Power 1         1.54 W (IA Cores)
    Power 2         0.24 W (GT)
    Power 3         9.34 W (Uncore)
    Power 4         0.88 W (DRAM)
    Voltage 0       0.66 Volts (VID)
    Voltage 1       +0.00 Volts (IA Offset)
    Voltage 2       +0.00 Volts (GT Offset)
    Voltage 3       +0.00 Volts (LLC/Ring Offset)
    Voltage 4       +0.00 Volts (System Agent Offset
```

)

Comment: I think your display needs more power than the old one, so the CPU can't use its maximum. please try turning your internal display off (F8 or something similar.....), connecting an external one (with extra power supply) and give us information about it

Comment: @Schwertspize thanks for the suggestion. The problem remains. Fyi: The new display is from another T440p with the same CPU configuration (broken mainboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many trial & error attempts, I found out what the issue was: My Laptop (cannot confirm if all Lenovo Laptops have this behavior) will throttle the CPU to the lowest setting if no battery is plugged-in. I don't know what the fine Lenovo engineers have been thinking...

Comment: There's probably a setting in BIOS to configure this...

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup (Lenovo T440, i5 4300U, 8GB DDR3 800mhz, SSD with Windows 7 preinstalled), and also experienced the computer running at the base clock speed randomly.

I opened the Lenovo Power Manager 6 app, and found that under the 'Advanced View' the system's Performance was set to 2 out of 7 green circles (7= max performance, 1= lowest performance) for all of the predefined scenarios (1: Video Playback; 2: Power Source Optimized; 3: Maximum Battery Life;  3: Times off (Presentation);  4: Airplane). I went to Maximum Performance and clicked the "Restore Default Settings" and saw the green circles increase from 2 to 6 (much better!) for the Performance setting. I then checked the Core Temp application I installed, and saw the CPU pick up some speed: jumping from 800mhz to 1.8ghz!

I'm not sure where the software wires got crossed, but refreshing the settings in Lenovo Power Manager 6 app seemed to fix my issue, at least for now! Good luck with your settings!

Answer (score 0):

Disable Hyperthreading on the BIOS - you will lose your 2.4 turbo clock but it will not be throttled down to 800Mhz!