# Intel SpeedStep not working in i3-380M

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-speed, speedstep

I have laptop Lenovo B560 instel i3-380M with Intel SpeedStep, however i am not getting full speed of CPU reported in CPU-Z when CPU is under 100% load.

Windows 7 x64

**EDIT**:
Guess it was battery issue (my battery is long gone even though plugged in), decried here: [Lenovo laptop with Intel CPU remains at lowest clock](https://superuser.com/questions/953972/lenovo-laptop-with-intel-cpu-remains-at-lowest-clock?rq=1)

However after running ThrottleStop once and exiting it does allow speedstep to go max speed!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has edited their question to indicate they have resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know Speed Step is not working? It is built into the CPU and is generally very reliable. It most likely is working properly

It may be that the CPU does not need to run at full speed to handle your load.

Make sure CPU-Z is up to date (Version 2.00 is current).

Make sure your drivers are up to date (Lenovo System Update).

Then do not forget that Windows 7 is very long out of date and there are not patches and updates for it.

Comment: actually there are patches, Extended Service Updates, been patching my old W7 PC's since it was retired. There is a cmd script out there to apply esu updates.

Comment: Speed step is built into the CPU and if the CPU is working then Speed Step is working. My comment about updates was also for third party software that no longer support Windows 7,  You are correct of course about paid extended support.

Comment: I know bcs CPU-Z shows real time CPU speed and multiplier. And running IntelBurnTest loads CPU to 100%

Comment: But your CPU has working speed step built in so something else beside speed step. 99% your speed step is working.

Comment: However after running ThrottleStop once and exiting it does allow speedstep to go max speed!    ....  Your speed step is part of the CPU circuitry and so as I said, if your computer is working (CPU working), so also is speed step. Software apps telling you otherwise were incorrect.

Comment: I do remember from very long long time ago that **Intel SpeedStep is controlled with Intel chipset driver** and had troubles with this in the past.

Here's another example i have MSI EX-620 laptop Windows 7 x64 and T7300 CPU speed step also faulty when i load cpu 100% it stays at Multiplier x4 and i am getting 796MHz only! Very easy to notice when playing video on youtube and it lags.

Comment: Speed step itself in in the CPU chip. Power Drivers may effect it, but not stop it from working. If speed step breaks down then the CPU will not work either so far as I know.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007073/processors.html

_Frequency selection is software-controlled_

Comment: True but your assertion was speed step was broken. That is not the same as software control.